# Change Diff Lines Colors In Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to change the diff lines colors on the left of the text editor?

In Visual Studio 2013 they used to be like this for the Dark theme:

[image]

But they changed the color in Visual Studio 2015 to a more khaki tone, and I don't like it:

[image]

I can't find them in the [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the VS 2015 Color Theme Editor. In a standard VS 2015 installation the colors are as shown in your first picture. If you want to change the colors, open the Options dialog with Tools + Options. In the Options window navigate to Environment, Fonts and Colors. In "Show settings for" select "Text Editor". In "Diplay items" look for "Track Changes after saved" and "Track Changes before saved".

[image]

Comment: They didn't change in the Blue theme, but did in the Dark theme.

Comment: Me too, but after you go black, you cant go back hahahaha... Seriously, you don't realize now, but try it and your eyes are going to thank you later.. All day coding with all this white light has its toll.

Comment: No, I can't switch to a dark theme. My colleague is on the dark side and if I would join him, we would lose a topic to argue about :-)